Change caption colors in GNU Screen depending on which window is active
I'd like the GNU Screen caption to change when entering a window where I have an active ssh session to a production machine, preferably from green to red. Current setup:
caption always "%?%{ Wk}%-Lw%?%{Gk}%n*%f %t%?(%u)%?%?%{Wk}%+Lw%? %{Gk}%=%c %{gk}%d/%M/%Y"

Any tips on what to search for?
